# How to make this type of texture/ shiny metallic but a bit grainy/ with a structure

Tags: texturing, materials

[image: Texture/Materials]

Hi!
I am trying to find out how to make this specific texture. It's shiny but there is something, a bit of imperfection. So far I have added the fingerprints to the roughness, but it is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a pink metallic texture and mix it with a *Glossy* node through a *Shader > Add Shader*, it will act like a sort of *Clearcoat* except you can give your *Glossy* the desired color (a dark pink). Add a bit of bump:

[image]